# Aerospike : LDT error in cross datacenter replication

Tags: aerospike, database, nosql

I ran into an error while inserting LDT bins recently.
I saw that normal bins were able to replicate well intra-cluster as well as cross datacenter.

But when I inserted LDT bins, they were not being replicated .
I used AMC (Aerospike Management Console) to check these statistics.
So is there an issue in statistics measurement in AMC in case of LDT ? or Is there an issue in cross datacenter replication for LDT ?

P.S : I now know the reason and posted this question so that it may help others.

Answer (score 2):

Cross Datacenter replication for LDT is not a supported feature yet.

Refer : https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/ldt-object-count-statistics-in-amc/991